# Angular 9 ngIf not working with firebase login popup

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angular9

I am having a strange issue with ngIf. Even after changing boolean values from false to true contents are not getting displayed on the UI.

I have two variables called `display_phone` set to false and `display_mail` set to true. After firebase Gmail login I toggle both variables, setting `display_phone` to true and `display_mail` to false. But ui is not changing. It is not rendering div tag which is set to the true value of `display_phone`

Thank you in advance

Here is code

.ts

```
 display_phone: boolean = false;
  display_mail: boolean = true;

    login(){

         this.afauth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.handle_user(res)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            this.presentAlert(JSON.stringify(err))
          })
       
     }

    handle_user(response){
    
      console.log('in handle user')
    
      this.display_mail = false
      this.display_phone = true
      console.log(this.display_phone) // true
      console.log(this.display_mail) // false
    }
```

html

```
  <div *ngIf="display_mail">display_mail</div>  // not hiding this tag after handle_user() function is executed
  <div *ngIf="display_phone">display_phone</div> // not displaying this tag after handle_user() function is executed
 
  <ion-button color="success" expand = "block" (click)="login()">  Login With Google </ion-button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this issue because you called `Firebase` promised function, and Angular is not aware of the result. So impossible for Angular to detect changes, and update view.

Don't worry, keep your code simple, you should use directly `Observable<User>` provided by AngularFire to receive update of current authentication state.

It's more powerful, because you will be notified also if user is disconnected, and any refresh of authentication state.

> AngularFireAuth.user provides you an Observable<User|null> to monitor your application's authentication State.

Excerpt of code from [official AngularFire repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md#5-getting-started-with-firebase-authentication):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user; else showLogin">
      <h1>Hello {{ user.displayName }}!</h1>
      <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    </div>
    <ng-template #showLogin>
      <p>Please login.</p>
      <button (click)="login()">Login with Google</button>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }
  login() {
    this.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

If you need to manipulate `User` into your code, you can subscribe to update :

```
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  
    this.subscription = auth.user.subscribe(user => {
      // do something with current user
      if (user) { ... }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Thierry Falvo for your answer. But how can I access additionalUserInfo. I need to know isnewuser field.

Comment: In fact it seems you're using an older version of AngularFire, aren't you ? I think version 6 with Angular 9 will solve your issue out of the box. Could you check which version of AngularFire you are using please ?

Comment: Yes. I am using angular fire version 5. Will update to version 6. Thank you